# Call event of bootstrap switch on change

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular and I normally in Javascript js file I can do a put action for change actual status of bootstrap switch like:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token
    },
    url: "http://myapi/api/usuarios/activar",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data) {
    },
    error: function(e) {
    }
  });
```

But now I implemented [Angular Bootstrap switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-bootstrap-switch) and my component.html looks like this:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
              <switch [status]="user.activo" [onText]="yes" [offText]="no" [onColor]="green" [offColor]="gray" [size]="normal" [disabled]="disabled"
                (statusChange)="onFlagChange($event)"></switch>
            </mat-cell>
```

As you can see it have `(statusChange)="onFlagChange($event)`, how it supposed I made that event in component, I know I should do something like this method in a  service:

```
postSwitch() {
    var switch = this.http
      .put(this.rootUrl + "api/usuarios/activar", this.options)
      .map((data: any) => data.json());
    return switch;
  }
```

then how can I call it into component.ts and execute it in event handle? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onFlagChange($event)` refers to a function that you define in your `component.ts` file, like this :

```
onFlagChange(event) {
  this.yourServiceName.postSwitch().subscribe(() => {
    //React to your HTTP request success
  }, (err) => {
    //React to your HTTP request error
  });
}
```

Your service template :

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  //Your service functions
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works it handle event as you say... but one question, is my put action correct? I always get: this.http.put is not a function

Comment: I edited my answer, dont forget the `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';` import